# Core Data Instantiating an Entity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm a very new beginner to Core Data, but It seems as though any time I instantiate an entity anywhere in my files other than Appdelegate.m, they crash. For example in my  MainViewController.m I merely wrote this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data"     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

}
```

Even just typing this I get SIGABRT. Every time. I have #imported my entity's NSManagedObject subclass to this file, but it keeps giving me SIGABRT. However, it doesn't do this whenever I instantiate an entity in my AppDelegate.m

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your `managedObjectContext` set to? As far as I can see you don't initialize it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSManagedObjectContext` is probably `nil`.  Make sure you pass your `NSManagedObjectContext` from your AppDelegate to your other view controllers.

In addition, be advised that the code you posted **does not** instantiate an entity. You are getting a reference to an `NSEntityDescription`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to insult you, but I saw your question and the response and thought I'd add a little. I agree with the solution, but if you are a newbie (as I was not too long ago), that may not be enough to get you what you need.

If you want to know how to see if your managedObjectContext is nil or not, just put the line of code before your NSEntityDescription command.

```
NSLog(@"managedObjectContext = %@",managedObjectContext);
```

If managedObjectContext was passed correctly, you will see something like the following:

2014-01-29 20:51:55.420 ModuleName[19405:70b] managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext: **0x10913de60**

Note the value 0x10913de60...this is a good value.

If managedObjectContext was not passed correctly, you will see something like the following:

2014-01-29 20:51:55.420 ModuleName[19405:70b] managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext: **(null)**

Note the value **(null)**...this is a bad value.

Also, there is a really good book available online that does a great job explaining Core Data.  The book is:

Zarra, Marcus S. (2013-02-05). Core Data: Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud (Pragmatic Programmers) (Kindle Location 3). Pragmatic Bookshelf. Kindle Edition.

I'm not hooked into these people and have no interest in their sales, but this book did get me over the hump on this sort of topic.  I think I paid about $15...was worth that to stop beating my head against the wall on stupid stuff.

Hope this helps!

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my AppDelegate.m in my viewDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions i did this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

This  made it so my managedObjectContext wasn't nil. Found my answer on a nice blog. Forgot the name, but he explained in detail why in some cases you would get SIGABRT doing Core Data.